# Android Notification PendingIntent action is executed instantly (but it shouldn't)

Tags: java, android

I'm new to developing in Android. I'm currently working on an app that allows you to put a reminder in the notifications (basically just triggers a notification with user inputed content).

However, I want to add a "Delete" button to the notification, I need that for a feature that I want to implement later. I went ahead and implemented a working system with a PendingIntent and a "normal" intent which forwards data to the BroadcastReceiver I set up.

**The problem I'm facing:** If I create a notification using the triggerNotification(View view) method is, that it instantly calls the NotificationReceiver and therefore deletes the notification I just created. But why on earth does it that?

From my understanding, the PendingIntent should only be finished when a user taps on the "Delete" message in the notification - or am I wrong?
I attached the files I'm working in right now, hopefully they'll help. :)

*MainActivity.java*

```
public void triggerNotification(View view) {

        // Create a notificationId for everything that's coming
        generateNotificationId();


        // Get user input from the text inputs, clear after user has input his text
        EditText editNotificationTitle = findViewById(R.id.inputNotificationTitle);
        EditText editNotificationText = findViewById(R.id.inputNotificationText);

        String notificationTitle = editNotificationTitle.getText().toString();
        String notificationText = editNotificationText.getText().toString();

        editNotificationTitle.getText().clear();
        editNotificationText.getText().clear();


        // Creates an intent to communicate with the BroadcastReceiver (NotificationReceiver) and
        // adds the notificationId to it
        Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        deleteIntent.setAction("ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION");
        deleteIntent.putExtra("ID", notificationId);
        sendBroadcast(deleteIntent);
        PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);


        // This is where the notification gets created
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "defaultNotificationChannel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_notify_round)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationText)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(notificationText))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_info_24, getString(R.string.delete), deletePendingIntent);


        // Sends the notification
        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
        managerCompat.notify(notificationId, builder.build());


        // Add snackbar to give the user feedback that the notification was created
        Snackbar.make(view, R.string.snackbar_notificationCreated, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }
```

*NotificationReveiver.java*

```
package com.example.notificationreminder;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    /**
     * Allows the user to delete the notification from an addAction in the notification.
     *
     * Grabs the generated notificationId, creates a NotificationManager and then cancels
     * the notification with the given id.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param intent
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int id = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.cancel(id);

    }


}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION">

             </action>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: `sendBroadcast(deleteIntent);` – Get rid of that line. That's what the `PendingIntent` is for; so that `sendBroadcast()` call can be made later, when you click the button.

Comment: @MikeM. Hmm okay, I removed that line before. Nothing happens then (which is good). But where do I need to implement that sendBroadcast() then?

Comment: You don't need to. Basically, the system will handle it when you click the button. That's what the `PendingIntent` does. It's kind of like a request for someone else to execute the `sendBroadcast()` call for you when the time comes. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. I mean yes, that was how I thought it would work before I implemented it. But if I remove the `sendBroadcast()`, the notification won't remove. That's because the notificationId that gets handed over to the `BroadcastReceiver` is "null". Which absolutely doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: Hang on a second. I think I misunderstood your description of the behavior. If the immediate `sendBroadcast()` is working to remove the notification, then the issue is likely that the `PendingIntent` is not updating as you expect. If you plan to allow multiple notifications at once, you can ensure a distinct one for each ID by passing `notificationId` instead of `0` in the `getBroadcast()` call, and amending the flags to `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't understood that the 0 was the id of the notification. Changed that, now it's working like a charm! Many thanks Mike, much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, that really sounds like `PendingIntent`s just not working intuitively. The system only creates those when absolutely necessary, and doesn't allow copies. However, the system doesn't consider extras on the `Intent` when determining equal `PendingIntent`s, so you have to force it to update.

Comment: Got it? Cool. No problem. Glad to help. Cheers!